# Links leak through semi-transparent DIV overlays in IE8

Tags: css

I just noticed something with IE8. I have a photo that is a link, and there's an partially transparent div over the image (just the bottom third of it or so) that is using this CSS code:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* handles the proper browsers */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#b2000000,endColorstr=#b2000000); /* for IE */
```

Unfortunately, when mousing over the div, the cursor is a pointer and clicking leads to the img's link. If I get rid of that filter and just make the background #000, it works fine and the overlay prevents any clicking. This behavior does not happen in Firefox or Chrome.

How can I work around this bug?

EDIT: Please note, this is not the same as an entire div with its opacity set to 0.7! That would cause the text inside of it (which I have) to also fade. This is strictly background color alpha.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/dxTdq/

Comment: A little hard to understand what's happening and what you are looking for. Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: Confidential. Lemme put together a fiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the SAME problem. You have to use an opaque color in the style and apply transparency via jquery

OR

make a semi-transparent .png as the background of the div

Comment: How can you set the background opacity via jQuery? Remember we're talking background opacity, not just plain old opacity. $('#mydiv').css('opacity', 0.7) would not achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Ok, I can think of one other way: make a div (#backdrop) inside the container div, and set #backdrop to background black opacity 70% via jQuery, and put another completely transparent div on top of that that contains the text. That way the backdrop is semi-transparent without affecting the opacity of the text.

Comment: I went with the PNG. :) Not worth the hassle of all the coding just to get a semi-transparent background!